# adding to a dictionary inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
stats = {'inventory': []}

stats['inventory'].append({'sand dollar': 10})
```

So basically I now want to add one to the amount of sand dollars. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `inventory` value is a list with a single item now, get it:

```
stats['inventory'][0]['sand dollar'] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since inventory is a list, you need to check every element in the list to find the one holding the sand dollars and do the increment for it:

```
>>> stats = {'inventory': []}
>>> stats['inventory'].append({'sand dollar': 10})
>>> stats
{'inventory': [{'sand dollar': 10}]}
>>> for item in stats['inventory']:
...     if isinstance(item, dict) and 'sand dollar' in item:
...         item['sand dollar'] += 1
...         break
... 
>>> stats
{'inventory': [{'sand dollar': 11}]}
```

I'd recommend making the inventory a dict and then you can do direct lookup for the inventory item name instead of searching in a potentially long list, much more convenient:

```
>>> stats = {'inventory': {}}
>>> stats['inventory']['sand dollar'] = 10
>>> stats
{'inventory': {'sand dollar': 10}}
>>> stats['inventory']['sand dollar'] += 1
>>> stats
{'inventory': {'sand dollar': 11}}
```